# Is it a good/bad idea to keep ThreadLocal between parallel loops?

Tags: c#, random, parallel-processing, thread-local

I'm trying to use ThreadLocal for parallel random generators. My test code is something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (MyClass myClass = new MyClass())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nPass {0}: ", i + 1);
                myClass.Execute();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nRandom Generators used: {0}", myClass.ListRNG.Count);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

sealed class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    ThreadLocal<RandomGenerator> threadRNG = new ThreadLocal<RandomGenerator>(() => 
                                                    new RandomGenerator(), true);

    public IList<RandomGenerator> ListRNG { get { return threadRNG.Values; } }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Action<int> action = (i) =>
        {
            bool repeat = threadRNG.IsValueCreated;
            List<int> ints = new List<int>();
            int length = threadRNG.Value.Next(10);
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                ints.Add(threadRNG.Value.NextInt(100));
            Console.WriteLine("Action {0}. ThreadId {1}{2}. Randoms({3}): {4}", 
                i + 1, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, 
                repeat ? " (repeat)" : "", length, string.Join(", ", ints));
        };

        Parallel.For(0, 10, action);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        threadRNG.Dispose();
    }
}

class RandomGenerator : Random
{
    public RandomGenerator() : base(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())
    {
    }

    public int NextInt(int maxValue)
    {
        return base.NextDouble() >= .5 ? base.Next(maxValue) : -base.Next(maxValue);
    }
}
```

Is it a good/bad idea to keep ThreadLocal between multiple executions of parallel loop? I'm afraid that there may accumulate unused instances of RandomGenerator. Especially when I have thousands of executions.

Update:
I tried another version of the test with another ThreadLocal constructor, allowing to access all values (I've changed the above code).

I also tried 100 000 executions of myClass.Execute() and found that only 17 instances of RandomGenerator were created. So I think (I hope) that everything is Ok with such an approach.

Comment: You are supposed to call ThreadLocal.Dispose() when the threads complete.  I wouldn't bother either.  Maybe this is all a bit overkill and you can make Random thread-safe?  It just takes a lock.  Timing isn't going to look that good in fake code like this but that's not so relevant.

Comment: @HansPassant, I based my code on [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/02/19/getting-random-numbers-in-a-thread-safe-way/) and [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness/) articles. I am going to use it in a genetic algorithm, so timing is important for me. I don't think that using a lock is better in this case.

Comment: Okay, then just do the obvious thing.  Call the ThreadLocal's Dispose() method to make you feel good.  Or don't since you'll never see the cost of it back.  It is entirely up to you.

Comment: @HansPassant, you maybe haven't noticed that MyClass implements IDisposable and I use it with `using` [statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), so there is no need to call Dispose() explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The per-thread values are rooted by the thread *if you don't demand to list all values*. So if threads die they don't keep their values live. Your code is fine.

It becomes even simpler if you use a `[ThreadStatic] static RandomGenerator rng;`.

Note, that thread-local access is a bit slow. You might be better off if you make each thread pull the RNG as little as possible and hold onto it for a while (for as long as architecturally possible).

Also, the .NET RNG is really slow and low-quality. Consider using XorShift and variants.

Comment: "So if threads die they don't keep their values live."  I didn't know that, thank you!  I avoided using ThreadStatic for this reason (though anyway I can assign a null to the static variable after its use). I'll consider using XorShift. Thanks again for your answer!